# How to merge git files in one directory and add the files to the staging area

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, github

How to initialize a git repository on a directory that contains a subdirectory that has git already initialized?

I am working on a MERN application and I have created a root folder "chatapp".

Inside the root directory, there are two sub-directories:

1. client
2. server

I am using React for the frontend and react comes with git already initialized.
I want to initialize git inside my root directory which contains the client subdirectory with git already initialized.

And when I run `git init`, it initialized well but when I run `git add`  to stage the files for commit, it brings an error: [screenshot of my code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzEy6.png)

I need to add both the client and server files to my git repository.
Do I need to first initialize git in the server file separately then merge or how do I add both files to the staging area?

How can I add do this without seeing the error to avoid conflicts in the repository?
Thank you,

Comment: You referring to git submodules. See this link for a good walk through from the git documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: If the error can be expressed in text, can you present it in text format? Not an image. See the StackOverflow guide below. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [do-not-post-image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Okay, I was just trying to bring a clear picture of what error I have encountered. Thank you, I just found a solution here: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Git Submodules and add the repo separately.

For example: `git submodule add https://<GIT_HOST>/server.git server` and `git submodule add https://<GIT_HOST>/client.git client`

Or, you could just not have those be Git repos.